# strtok() behavior is different across compilers

Tags: c, strtok

I wrote a program which parses a string according to this format:

```
somethingsomething:number:
```

On my computer, this program works flawlessly.
However, once I have uploaded the code and compiled it on the school's computer, `strtok()` has a different behavior.

For instance, with this string: `p2test/f4.txt:1:`, on my computer the first token would be `p2test/f4.txt`. However, on the school's computer, the token ends up as `p2test/f4.t`.

Here is the code segment:

```
            char *token;
            char delim[1] = ":";

            if ((token = strtok(tmp_string, delim)) != NULL) {
                ...
            }
```

Here, `tmp_string` would be `p2test/f4.txt:1:`.

Here is my computer's compiler version: gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)

Here is my school's compiler version: gcc version 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388] (SUSE Linux)

Comment: Undefined behavior is different accross computers, please post the rest of the code, exactly how is `tmp_string` generated.

Comment: `char delim[1] = ":";`  This compiled?  There are two characters in that string literal, but you declared an array of 1 char.  The other character is the null terminator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh you're right! That is strange since I turned on all warnings and pedantic too.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That's legal C (but not C++).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I completely missed that...

Comment: @cremno - Yeah, you're right.  So that's a memory overwrite bug.

Comment: See my comment on PaulMcKenzie's answer about there not being a '\0' allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another issue is that you have a memory overwrite here:

```
char delim[1] = ":";
```

There are two characters in the string, not 1.  Much safer to do this:

```
char delim[] = ":";
```

Comment: `char delim[1] = ":";` intializes `delim` to one char and does not imply there is a following `'\0'`.  It is not "safer" to use `char delim[] = ":";`, it or `char delim[2] = ":";` is what the algorithm is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the couple of issues noted in the comments, it looks like there is a bigger problem with the code. According to the description of the getline() function in the man pages:

> ```
>   If  *lineptr  is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then get‐
>   line() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should
>   be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.
>
>   Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer
>   to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the buffer is not
>   large  enough  to  hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3),
>   updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.
> ```

You did not initialize tmp_string, hence its value is some uninitialized junk that points to some random address, and the second alternative behavior of getline(), described above, occurs.

This looks like undefined behavior to me.

P.S. You did initialize the length value to 0 bytes, which, according to getline()'s man page causes it to call realloc. So, it looks to me your code ends up, indirectly, passing a garbage pointer to realloc.

Comment: I've actually noticed this in another function I wrote while debugging in gdb. Is it safer to set all uninitialized pointers to NULL in the future then?